# Bootstrap 3 - Display text and an image in the same row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm starting out a website using BootStrap 3 framework. Here's the section of the code that I have an issue with:

```
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                         <div class="brand">
                            <h1><a href="index.html">Test Text.</a></h1>
                            <div class="line-spacer"></div>
                            <p><span>Some more test Text</span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <img src="img/devices.png" />
                    </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

Here's what the output looks like:

[image: test screenshot]

How do I get the image along the same row as the text? I tried placing the `<img>` within the `col-md-8` div tag, tried without specifying any `col` div value, but none of that worked. Any help is appreciated. The CSS is the generic bootstrap min css.

Comment: Change col-md-12 by col-md-4 :         ===>  1 row = 12  (8+4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to split the area up in two parts, but always keep in mind that bootstrap standard uses 12 grid system.

So if you want the two next to each other u use...

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Here your text
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <img />
    </div>
</div>
```

That should fix your issue, remember up count goes over 12 it wraps.

Answer (score 3):

Your columns have to always add up to a total of 12 and your code should be similar to the below:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            CONTENT
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            CONTENT
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Have a good read over the Bootstrap Docs on their Grid System:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid